# How to choose custom AMI for EMR via Airflow

Tags: python-3.6, boto3, airflow, amazon-emr, amazon-ami

I'm spinning up an EMR cluster via Airflow and run a PySpark job on it.  I want to use a Custom AMI to boot up the cluster via Airflow. I'm following the boto3 syntax found in the docs online but the AMI is not being picked up. Is there something wrong with my syntax? Can anyone provide some guidance as to how to proceed to check where the issue lies?

(https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow)

- Ubuntu:18.04,
- Python: 3.6.7,
- awscli: 1.16.166,
- airflow: 1.10.0
- boto: 2.49.0,
- boto3: 1.9.156,
- botocore: 1.12.156

I've tried creating the EMR cluster via airflow cmd in the cli:

```sh
airflow test test_emr_custom_ami emr_create_cluster 2019-05-01
```

Cluster is created but without the CustomAmiId specified.

```py
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_create_job_flow_operator import EmrCreateJobFlowOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_terminate_job_flow_operator import EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
from ast import literal_eval
from datetime import timedelta
"""
   DAG to test creating an EMR cluster via Airflow 
   while specifying a custom AMI.

   The DAG only creates and terminates an EMR cluster
   in the region of aws_default airflow connection
"""

##########################################################################
##
#   EMR/SPARK SETTINGS
##
##########################################################################
execution_dt = "{{ ds }}"
emr_template_args = {
    'cluster_name': 'test__custom_ami_emr_{}'.format(execution_dt),
    'log_uri': 's3://xxxxxx/test_custom_ami_emr/logs',
    'release_label': 'emr-5.16.0',
    # EMR instance fleets
    'master_fleet_instances': "\
                  {'InstanceType': 'r4.xlarge',\
                  'BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice':30,\
                  'WeightedCapacity': 1\
                   },\
                  {'InstanceType': 'r4.2xlarge',\
                  'BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice': 30,\
                  'WeightedCapacity': 1},\
                  {'InstanceType': 'r4.4xlarge',\
                   'BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice': 30,\
                   'WeightedCapacity': 1}\
    ",\
    'core_fleet_instances': "\
                   {'InstanceType': 'r4.xlarge',\
                    'BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice': 30,\
                    'WeightedCapacity':1},\
                    {'InstanceType': 'r4.2xlarge',\
                    'BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice': 30,\
                    'WeightedCapacity': 2},\
                    {'InstanceType': 'r4.4xlarge',\
                    'BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice': 30,\
                    'WeightedCapacity': 4}\
    ",\
    'timeout_fleet_minutes': 20,\
    'core_target_spot_capacity': 11,
    'master_target_spot_capacity': 1,
    'emr_ec2_subnet_ids': 'subnet-xxx, subnet-xxx, subnet-xxx',
    'action_on_failure': 'TERMINATE_CLUSTER',
    'availability_zones': 'eu-west-1a, eu-west-1b, eu-west-1c',

    'ec2_keyname': 'xxx',
    'visible_to_all_users': True,
    'keeps_job_alive_when_no_steps': True,

    # Applications to install/run on cluster. Pass as list
    'applications': {'Hadoop', 'Hue', 'Spark', 'Hive', 'Ganglia'},

    # Tags
    'project': 'test_custom_ami_emr',
    'owner': 'data_management',
    'data_classification': 'confidential',
    'environment': 'dev'
}

# Glue metastore configuration
metastore_configs = [
    {
        "Classification": "hive-site",
        "Properties": {
            "hive.metastore.client.factory.class": "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory"
        }
    },
    {
        "Classification": "spark-hive-site",
        "Properties": {
            "hive.metastore.client.factory.class": "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory"
        }
    }
]


def get_tags(args):
    return [
        {
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': args['cluster_name'],
        },
        {
            'Key': 'cost_center',
            'Value': 'xxx',
        },
        {
            'Key': 'application',
            'Value': 'spark',
        },
        {
            'Key': 'project',
            'Value': args['project'],
        },
        {
            'Key': 'owner',
            'Value': args['owner'],
        },
        {
            'Key': 'data_classification',
            'Value': args['data_classification'],
        },
        {
            'Key': 'environment',
            'Value': args['environment'],
        }
    ]


def get_emr_fleet_instance_template(args):
    """
    Get the template necessary to spin up an EMR Cluster using INSTANCE FLEETS.

    Pass the key values below in a dictionary. 
    """
    emr_apps = [{'Name': app} for app in args['applications']]
    template = {
        'Name': args['cluster_name'],
        'LogUri': args['log_uri'],
        'ReleaseLabel': args['release_label'],
        'RequestedEc2AvailabilityZones ': args['availability_zones'].replace(' ', '').split(','),
        'Instances': {
            'InstanceFleets': [
                {
                    "Name": "MasterFleet",
                    "InstanceFleetType": "MASTER",
                    "TargetSpotCapacity": args['master_target_spot_capacity'],
                    "InstanceTypeConfigs": convert_string_var_to_dict(args['master_fleet_instances'])
                },
                {
                    "Name": "CoreFleet",
                    "InstanceFleetType": "CORE",
                    "TargetSpotCapacity": args['core_target_spot_capacity'],
                    "LaunchSpecifications": {
                        "SpotSpecification": {
                            "TimeoutDurationMinutes": args['timeout_fleet_minutes'],
                            "TimeoutAction": "SWITCH_TO_ON_DEMAND"
                        }
                    },
                    "InstanceTypeConfigs": convert_string_var_to_dict(args['core_fleet_instances'])
                }
            ],
            'Ec2KeyName': args['ec2_keyname'],
            'Ec2SubnetIds': args['emr_ec2_subnet_ids'].replace(' ', '').split(','),
            'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': True if args['keeps_job_alive_when_no_steps'] is None else args['keeps_job_alive_when_no_steps'],
            'TerminationProtected': False,
        },
        'VisibleToAllUsers': args['visible_to_all_users'],
        'JobFlowRole': 'xxx',
        'ServiceRole': 'xxx',
        'Applications': emr_apps,
        'Tags': get_tags(args),
        'Steps': [
            {
                'Name': 'Setup Debugging',
                'ActionOnFailure': 'TERMINATE_CLUSTER',
                'HadoopJarStep': {
                    'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                    'Args': ['state-pusher-script']
                }
            },
        ],
        'Configurations': metastore_configs,
        'CustomAmiId': 'ami-xxx' 
    }

    return template

def convert_string_var_to_dict(text):
    """
    Function that transforms a string that has the format of a JSON or more precisely a List of Dictionaries
    to a real list of dictionaries.
    :param text: The format of the string is as a list of Dictionaries
    :type text: string
    :return: List of Dictionaries
    :type return: List
    """
    output_list = []
    for item in text.split('},'):
        for ch in ['\r', '\n', ' ']:
            if ch in text:
                item = item.replace(ch, "")
        if item.endswith('}'):
            output_list.append(literal_eval(item))
        else:
            output_list.append(literal_eval(item + "}"))
    return output_list


JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = get_emr_fleet_instance_template(emr_template_args)

dag = DAG(
    "test_emr_custom_ami",
    default_args={
        "owner": "airflow",
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "email": ["xxx@xxx"],
        "email_on_failure": True,
        "email_on_retry": False,
        "retries": 0,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
        "start_date": "2019-04-01"
    },
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    catchup=False
)

# Create cluster
t_emr_create_cluster = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
    task_id='emr_create_cluster',
    job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES, # define custom AMI here
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    emr_conn_id='aws_default',
    queue='light',
    dag=dag
)

# Terminate cluster
t_emr_terminate_cluster = EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator(
    task_id='emr_terminate_cluster',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('emr_create_cluster', key='return_value') }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    queue='light',
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,
    dag=dag
)

t_emr_create_cluster >> t_emr_terminate_cluster
```

I expect the EMR cluster created to have the custom AMI but it doesn't. I check this by looking at "Configuration details --> Custom AMI ID: " in the AWS Console when I select the created cluster.